# Elasticsearch: compute aggregation metric from other aggregation metrics

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, metrics

Elasticsearch lets you compute metrics on a bucket from the fields of the hits in the document. But what if I want to compute a metric from other metrics on the aggregation.

For example, I'm storing data on advertising campaigns in Elasticsearch. I aggregate documents by date, and add `daily_spend` and `daily_clicks` metrics (by summing up the `spend` and `clicks` metrics on the documents in each `day` bucket). Now I want to add a `cpc` metric, which is computed from the `daily_spend` and `daily_clicks` metrics. How do I do that?

Here's my query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "campaign_id": 1234
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "day": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "day"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "daily_spend": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "spend"
                    }
                },
                "daily_clicks": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "clicks"
                    }
                },
                "cpc": {
                    //daily_spend/daily_clicks
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey got any solution for this problem >

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to pull the data from the other two aggregations and do additional operations on them.

Your best bet is to do that division operation on the value of the `daily_spend` and `daily_clicks` aggregations after you have retrieved the data from the query.